# Do content testing tasks need to run in Delivery environment?

Tags: content-testing

In my Sitecore 8.2 installation, i have the following tasks:

```
+---sitecore
|   \---system
|       \---Tasks
|           \---Schedules
|               \---Content Testing
|                   \---Calculate Statistical Relvancy
|                   \---Rebuild Suggested Tests Index
|                   \---Suspend Corrupted Tests
|                   \---Try Finish Test
```

Since i use Solr for indexing, i'm pretty confident that the `Rebuild Suggested Test Index` should only trigger on the Authoring environment and therefore needs to be set to `Never Publish`. Does anybody know whether this needs to be done for the other 3 tasks as well? Or does every Delivery server in a scaled environment need to run those 3 tasks?

Answer (score 3):

Is not needed because I can see Rebuild Suggested Test Index commmand is using sitecore_suggested_test_index index.

Sitecore search indexes required for different types of servers in a scaled environment can be seen in below picture :

[image]

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/search_indexes_required_in_a_scalable_environment

Comment: Hi Vlad. I was pretty confident about this one. More intresting would be the other ones as i don't find any information out there :)